# Can't upload app on google console because it exceeds 150mb limit

Tags: google-play-console

I've been trying to upload a app that is basically a flipbook in an app. The size of the flip book is 400mb and it's file type is html. What can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxytD.png)

I tried the unity PAD thing but it didn't work.

Comment: For AWS, I'd move the images into a separate storage bucket (S3 storage) or file storage (EBS) instead of embedding them in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Study texture import settings and discover how to lower the resolution of your assets (probably images based on your description): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Textures.html

Beyond that you can use asset bundles to download the data from a privately hosted location after the initial app has been downloaded: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

But I think the first step should be sufficient to fix the issue.